# Serializing an Object that contains 3 lists of different objects Protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

I've been reading up on the capabilities of this package and I was just wondering if it is even possible to serialize an object which contains 3 lists of different objects, or if I would be wasting my time trying to switch over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up switching to MSGPack instead of PhotoBuf, it was much easier to use with better documentation and had no problem serializing the data in it's current format. After wrestling with PhotoBuf for a few hours, I got MSGPack working in 25 mins in C# and got it receiving and deserializing the data in JS after about an hour. Great choice to switch!